# JavaScript Problem in Firefox 4.0

Tags: javascript

I have some problem regarding JavaScript compatibility. I am using below code to clean text box blur data when click on that Text Box.This code is working fine in Firefox 3.6 & IE, but not supportable on Firefox 4. Some errors are there in error console like `clearTextFrom is not defined` & `clearTextTo is not define`. Please check below code & suggest me how can i run this code on FF4.

```
function clearTextFrom() {
    if(document.getElementById("size_from").value=="From Year")
        document.getElementById("size_from").value="";
}

function clearTextTo() {
    if(document.getElementById("size_to").value=="To Year")
        document.getElementById("size_to").value="";
}
```

Waiting for your quick response.

Thanks in Advance
Tanu

EDIT:

```
<div class="yearsearch"> 
<input type='text' style='width: 60px;' name='size_from' maxlength='4' size='17' id='size_from' onfocus='clearTextFrom();' onkeyup="validNumbers(document.getElementById('size_from')); sync();"/> 
<input type='text' style='width: 60px;' name='size_to' maxlength='4' size='17' id='size_to' onfocus='clearTextTo();' onkeyup="validNumbers(document.getElementById('size_to'));"/>
</div>
```

This is the code which i am using to call these functions.

Comment: Please, make the Codes as Codes to understand more.

Comment: Can you post the code where you invoke this? There is raised outside of your functions (which look good to me).

Comment: sorry what do u mean. i could not understand.

Comment: <div class="yearsearch">
<input type='text' style='width: 60px;' name='size_from'  maxlength='4' size='17'  id='size_from'  onfocus='clearTextFrom();' onkeyup="validNumbers(document.getElementById('size_from')); sync();"/>
   <input type='text' style='width: 60px;' name='size_to'  maxlength='4' size='17'  id='size_to'  onfocus='clearTextTo();' onkeyup="validNumbers(document.getElementById('size_to'));"/>   
  </div> This is the code which i am using to call these functions.

Comment: please don't post code in a comment - edit your question and add the code there.

Answer (score 1):

Change to this :

```
<script language="javascript">
    function clearTextFrom(item) {
        if(item.value=="From Year")
            item.value="";
    }

    function clearTextTo(item) {
        if(item.value=="To Year")
            item.value="";
    }
</script>


<div class="yearsearch"> 
<input type='text' style='width: 60px;' name='size_from' maxlength='4' size='17' id='size_from' onfocus='clearTextFrom(this);' value="From Year"/> 
<input type='text' style='width: 60px;' name='size_to' maxlength='4' value="To Year" size='17' id='size_to' onfocus='clearTextTo(this);'/> 
</div>
```

in this code you are sending each textbox to related function. I tested and worked for me in FF4.0

sample : http://jsfiddle.net/fkP2P/

Comment: look at the sample url in edited post. [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/fkP2P/) working in FF 4.0

Comment: Are you kidding me? I am browsing that sample page in FF 4.0? does any body else have this problem ?